# Que dados posso obter de um usuário?

Tags: javascript, api

Estou criando uma landing page que tem por objetivo capturar o máximo possível de informações dos usuários que podem se tornar futuros clientes

Até agora consigo pegar a localização por geolocalização no javascript (se o usuário permitir) ou pelo IP no servidor

Ouvi falar de uma API da google que permite recuperar as informações de usuário se o mesmo estiver conectado na sua conta, pesquisei mas não encontrei, alguém conhece?

Que outras informações eu posso obter do usuário?

Comment: Por que ampla demais, a pessoa que quer fechar a pergunta poderia explicar o motivo? Como posso melhorar? Observação, não é necessário mostrar como pegar os dados (mas um norte ajudaria), apenas se é possível obter, se tiver alguma dúvida farei outras perguntas para cada um

Comment: O SOpt não é um fórum. É um site de perguntas e respostas e a  pergunta tem que ser feita de forma a obter uma resposta canônica e não uma opinião. A resposta mais curta à sua resposta é:  você vai obter somente o que o usuário permitir.

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade entendo que dificilmente vai conseguir uma informação do usuário sem a sua autorização, mas que informações são essas? Acredito ser uma pergunta válida

Comment: Guilherme, você gostaria de saber quais são os dados permitidos capturar em uma landing page ou quais dados são possíveis capturar além dos campos digitados?

Comment: @GabrielCarvalho quais dados são possíveis capturar além dos campos digitados, por exemplo, a localização que mencionei e os dados básicos mencionados na resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do usuário em si não há muito o que se obter, uma vez que o navegador não guarda informação do usuário. Quem guada informação são os sites, em *cookies*, mas isso já sabemos que não podemos ler de outros sites (domínios).

Portanto, nos resta algumas informações da navegação do usuário, que existem no `DOM`, nos objetos `window` e `navigator` por exemplo:

**navigator.appName**: nome do navegador (aplicação usando para navegar); 
**navigator.appVersion**: detalhes das versões do ambiente do usuário (sistema operacional e navegador), exemplo:

> 5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.75 Safari/537.36

**navigator.geolocation**: retorna a geolocalização do usuário (se permitido) através do navegar, que você já descobriu.
**navigator.platform**: plataforma do navegador (sistema operacional).
**navigator.language**: linguagem usada no navegador, exemplo: `pt-BR`;
**window.screen**: tamanho da tela

Entre outras. Informações mais específicas sobre o usuário (nome, email, etc), somente o que ele informou em algum site ou serviço e que possa ser compartilhado. Existem apis para isso e, com o devido consentimento do usuário você pode obter esses dados. Aqui alguns exemplos de  serviços mais comuns:

[Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) e [SDK API Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)
[Google API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/)
[Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs.html)

Comment: A resposta é antiga, mas ainda é válido se ater ao fato de que é possível obter cookies e sessões de sites. Desde que o site guarde a informação e o navegador processe, isso se torna possível, inclusive é bastante utilizado em `Phishings`.

Answer (score 2):

Sendo bem direto, se você usar a autenticação via *OAuth2* você tem acesso a informações básicas de perfil do usuário logado (com as devidas permissões), tais como:

- *BasicProfile.getId()*
- *BasicProfile.getName()*
- *BasicProfile.getGivenName()*
- *BasicProfile.getFamilyName()*
- *BasicProfile.getImageUrl()*
- *BasicProfile.getEmail()*

Para essas informações peguei por base a [documentação](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetbasicprofile) referente ao *client* para *Javascript*.

Recomendo uma leitura nas guias disponíveis pelo [blog da *google developers*](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).

Comment: na verdade não tem muita lógica utilizar uma autenticação numa landing page.

Comment: Concordo, apenas mostrei uma das formas de obter dados após o usuário estar conectado a uma conta *google*, não necessariamente se aplica uma *landing page*, mas pode ser útil de alguma forma pra ele, visto que esse tipo de informação não tem como ser obtido apenas por o usuário acessar a *landing page*.

Comment: sim, mas a dúvida era capturar os dados de uma landing page, e não uma solução qualquer utilizando OAuth